# How can i stop the delay from setInterval?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using setInterval do show a slideshow, and i would like to show the slideshow immediately, how can i prevent the delay from the beginning?

Code:

```
 setInterval(
        function() {
                        $("body, #resp-background").css({
                'background-image': 'url(' + pics[i] + ')',
                '-webkit-transition': 'background-image .25s ease-in-out',
                'transition': 'background-image .25s ease-in-out;',
                '-moz-transition': 'background-image .25s ease-in-out;',
                'background-size': 'background-image .25s ease-in-out;',
                '-o-background-size': 'cover',
                '-moz-background-size': 'cover',
                '-webkit-background-size': 'cover'
            });

            $('.s-description').html(descriptions[i]);
            i++;
            if (i >= pics.length) i = 0;

        }, 4200);
```

Jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/kx1fgsox/3/

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
var slider = function() { /*your code here*/ };
slider(); //execute immediately
setInterval(slider, 4200); //start interval loop
```

- also, you should initialize your `i` to be `0`

Answer (score 0):

Or even cleaner:

```
(function loop () { /* do stuff */ })();
window.setTimeout(loop, 1000);
```

This way, the function auto executes on init.

Comment: loop won't be defined if you do this (which is the purpose for using http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)